# Mysql : get conditional and unconditional data with single query

Tags: mysql

I need to get the count of some data with and without a conditional statement. Now what i'm doing is I wrote 2 different queries ie

```
$sql = "select COUNT(`id`) as totalcount from `table1`";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

$sql = "select COUNT(`id`) as count1 from `table1` where `field_name` = 'someting' ";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$condRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
```

Can I write both this in a single query ?

Comment: COUNT(*), SUM(fieldname = something)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it as

```
SELECT 
COUNT(`id`) as totalcount,
sum(field_name='someting') as count1
FROM `table1`;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e84b6/1)

Comment: but here if we add a where condition to the query the total count will not be correct..right !

Comment: The statement `sum(field_name='someting')` works as where meaning get the count `where field_name='someting'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select COUNT(`id`) as totalcount, SUM(field_name='something') as conditional_total
from `table1`
```